# FusionCharts on HTTPS, mixed content warning

Tags: https, fusioncharts

I am having trouble with the dreaded "mixed content" warning in IE8 and after checking for and eliminating any traces of 'http:' in my code, I have discovered that the following line is the cause:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plugins/FusionCharts_Intranet/Charts/FusionCharts.js"></script>
```

I have read on the FusionCharts site that it will only work over HTTPS when certain methods are used. However if I create a test page with ONLY the above line in it, it throws the error.

Has anyone experienced this before? I am happy to experiment with different methods of data retrieval (json, whatever), but the fact that an error is being thrown before any charts are even generated is puzzling.

In IE9 I get the same error but it is 'bypassable'. In IE8 it completely stops the page loading (it seems to stop jquery from loading, which is used when the page is loaded).

Thanks,
valoukh

Comment: This is fixed in FusionCharts XT v3.2.2 Service Release 5 But the Band-aid solution posted by Shamasis also works!

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that the upcoming release of FusionCharts will hotfix this. But before that, there is a simple code edit that can suppress these errors:

1. Open `FusionCharts.js` file in a text editor.
2. Check whether the release version (in the file comment says `@version fusioncharts/3.2.4-release.8565` (for later versions, this may not work.)
3. Find the text `src=javascript:void(0)` (there should be only one instance)
4. Replace the text with `src='//:'`
5. Save the file!

This should fix the error.